# Lack of a text input field in zenity file selector

Tags: xfce, gui, dialog, zenity, select

I have Debian 9 with xfce and installed zenity to use it to select directory paths. I use it in this way

```
zenity --file-selection --directory
```

The GUI selector looks as below. It has not the text input field where a user may put out directory paths. The path in the selector is made of buttons. How can I turn it to the text input field?

[image]

#### Edit

I have seen a select box as below  in a zenity tutorial.

[image]

It actually has the field.

Comment: You use the buttons to navigate up/down/across the directory tree.

Comment: But I want to use the text input field.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> turns it. When the select box is displayed one may press it.